# NoMethodError and Refinery Engine in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud, refinerycms, refinery

I'm trying to reuse a refinery engine on another page in refinery. In the routes.rb i've included:

```
    match 'locations/:location_id/' => "locations/#index"
```

What is  the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should create your routes in the engine route file.

Normally you would just add

```
resources :locations
```